# Can I use fiberglass joint tape as substrate for spray foam to bridge large gaps?

Tags: spray-foam

I have a 2 inch gap in my drywall ceiling I need to spray fireblock foam into. Can I use the fiberglass drywall mesh tape to give the foam something to hang onto so that I can bridge the gap and the foam doesn't fall back down.

Can I spray through the foam mesh if I can't get behind it?

Comment: Fwiw, spray foam won’t go through drywall mesh tape. If you gotta do something like this (not recommended; see answer about patching), 1/2” mesh would be my pick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best bet is to repair the ceiling so there is not a 2 inch gap.
2 inches is a substantial gap to have in-between drywall surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Spray foam is extremely sticky. I'd simply move a tool along as you spray to force the foam bead to make contact with the adjacent materials. As soon as it does it should cling in place. The tool could be as simple as a hunk of lumber.

Comment: Agreed. However, if one is hoping to get it to stick to a vertical surface or to bridge a horizontal opening it is generally _not_, in my experience, sticky _enough_ to do that.

Comment: It won't stick well to a _single_ vertical surface. It will, though, grab _two_ such surfaces. Standard spray foam expands very quickly. With the technique I describe I have confidence of success.